# Parse Cloud Code query after save don't works

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

After saving an array of objects, I do a query for count the number of elements of a class, but the code doesn't run.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveItem", function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    ... (Updating objects...)

    Parse.Object.saveAll([item, activity], {
        success: function(list) {
            response.success("saved"); // <--- THE OBJECTS ARE SAVED, ALLRIGHT

            var query = new Parse.Query("Item"); // <--- FROM HERE
            query.count({
                 success: function(count) {
                      console.log("inside count"); // <--- NOT ENTER HERE!!
                 },
                 error: function(error) {
                      // The request failed
                 }
            });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to complete your operations *before* calling response.success("saved")

Calling response.success is effectively killing the rest of your code.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveItem", function(request, response) {

    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    //... (Updating objects...)

    Parse.Object.saveAll([item, activity], {
        success: function (list) {
            var query = new Parse.Query("Item");

            query.count({
                success: function (count) {
                    response.success(count);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    // The request failed
                    response.error("Unable to count items...");
                }
            });
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error(error);
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You, but where I put the response? Look this change please http://pastebin.com/DQ3Gn24F

Comment: Added a suggestion for your code now. Haven't had time for proofreading, so keep that in mind when trying...